# Redux TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'merge' of 'definitions[meta.arg.endpointName]' as it is undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

**authSlice**

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState: { userData: null, accessToken: null },

    reducers: {

        setCredentials: (state, action) => {
            console.log("Store ", action.payload);
            const { userData, accessToken } = action.payload;
            state.userData = userData;
            state.accessToken = accessToken;
        },

        logOut: (state, action) => {
            state.userData = null;
            state.accessToken = null;
        }
    }
});

export const { setCredentials, logOut } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;

export const selectCurrentUser = state => state.auth.userData;

export const selectCurrentToken = state => state.auth.accessToken;
```

**authApiSlice**

```
import { apiSliceUser } from "./apiSliceUser";

export const authApiSlice = apiSliceUser.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: builder => ({

        login: builder.mutation({

            query: credentials => {
                console.log(credentials)
                return {
                    url: '/login',
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: { ...credentials },
                }
            }

        }),
        invalidatesTags: ["users"],
    })
})

export const { useLoginMutation } = authApiSlice;
```

**apiSliceUser**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { logOut, setCredentials } from './authSlice';

//* This unit is responsible for login & Refreshing Token functionality... :)

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/users',
    credentials: 'include',

    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
        const token = getState().auth.accessToken;
        console.log(getState().auth);

        if (token) {
            headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        }

        return headers;
    }

});

const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {

    let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);

    console.log("Result : ", result);

    //! Since the access token expires then try to refresh the token... :)

    if (result?.error?.originalStatus === 403) {
        console.log('Sending Refresh Token');

        const refreshResult = await baseQuery('/refresh', api, extraOptions);

        if (refreshResult?.data) {
            const userData = api.getState().auth.userdata;

            api.dispatch(setCredentials({ userData, accessToken: refreshResult.accessToken }));

            result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
            console.log(result);
        }
        else {
            api.dispatch(logOut())
        }
    }

    return result;
}

export const apiSliceUser = createApi({
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    tagTypes: ["users"],
    endpoints: builder => ({
    })
})
```

store

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import postSlice from './Posts/postSlice';
import userSlice from './Users/userSlice';
import { apiSlice } from './Posts/apiSlice';
import { apiSliceUser } from './Authentication/apiSliceUser';
import authReducer from './Authentication/authSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        posts: postSlice,
        user: userSlice,
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
        [apiSliceUser.reducerPath]: apiSliceUser.reducer,
        auth: authReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware).concat(apiSliceUser.middleware),
    devTools: true,
});
```

Basically, I 'm setting up an store to achieve JWT Authentication ? But couldn't be able to achieve this getting this as an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'merge' of 'definitions[meta.arg.endpointName]' as it is undefined.
    at @reduxjs_toolkit_query_react.js?v=086dfd1c:999:13
    at updateQuerySubstateIfExists (@reduxjs_toolkit_query_react.js?v=086dfd1c:909:5)
    at @reduxjs_toolkit_query_react.js?v=086dfd1c:995:9
    at chunk-CMRBLURP.js?v=086dfd1c:2347:20
    at Immer2.produce (chunk-CMRBLURP.js?v=086dfd1c:904:20)
    at chunk-CMRBLURP.js?v=086dfd1c:2346:18
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at reducer (chunk-CMRBLURP.js?v=086dfd1c:2327:25)
    at reducer (chunk-CMRBLURP.js?v=086dfd1c:2752:16)
    at combination (chunk-CMRBLURP.js?v=086dfd1c:302:31)
```

Can anyone please help me figure out what i'm doing wrong, I 'm very new to use redux in such a way if possible please explain in some brief manner or share associated resources to handle or understand it. Thank You !

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Any ideas what "endpoint" wouldn't have a name? Does this error just happen when starting the app, or do you have to interact with some UI first to cause it? We need some debugging details. Is there anything else in the console that could hint to you where in the code the problem exists?

Comment: When applicable starts this error appears

Comment: "The error is essentially caused by the apiUserSlice unit. The error does not occur when this unit is excluded from the store."

Comment: Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Ashlok2003/SOCIALX/main

Comment: Sorry For the late response, But I couldn't be able to set up the codesandbox properly . Please run the project through codesandbox terminal. 
For Backend :
 cd ./Backend
 node server.js
For Frontend :
 npm run dev

Comment: Or Else Follow the root directory json file to setup the project :)

Comment: Error has been resolved, Actually The error happen because of non-unique reducer path once I change it the error solved. thanks @DrewReese for you valuable time.

Comment: Ah good. I wasn't able to open a terminal in the sandbox you linked so I was just combing through the code. FWIW you very likely wouldn't have needed a full front and backend to reproduce the issue, a small UI demo with mocked base queries would likely have been sufficient.